# Navigate to a react-native screen undefined prop navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am working on a react-native app and currently have two screens accessible using tabs on the bottom. I would like to navigate to a particular screen onPress and am trying to trigger the navigation from one screen to the next.

To do this, It looks like I need to pass in a prop to the screen and access it as follows:

```
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
```

And then do:

```
onPress={() => navigate('Result', {result: results[i]})}
```

Although, this generates an error saying that the `navigation` prop isn't defined. I am not clear on where this prop is suppose to come from / how to pass it in to the screen. Ideally, Id like every screen to have access to the navigation stack. I've been having a really tough time getting this to work and appreciate any advise on how to do this.

**Relevant navigator code:**

AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

    export default createSwitchNavigator({
      // You could add another route here for authentication.
      // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
      Main: MainTabNavigator,
    });
```

Comment: The `navigation` prop is passed to screen components in navigator(tab navigator in your case). Can you post the navigator's code?

Comment: @NULLSWEΔT, see edited, I've added the code.

Comment: The navigation prop will automatically be passed to any and all components that use `react-navigation`'s methods like: `createStackNavigator()`, `createBottomTabNavigator`, etc. Can you show the code where you're trying to access `this.props.navigation`? If you want to pass it to a component that isn't using `createStackNavigator()` then you'll need to pass it to the component prop like you normally would: `<SomeComponent navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate} />`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `withNavigation` HOC to pass `navigation` prop into a component.

Example Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return <Button onPress={() => navigate('Result', {result: results[i]})} />;
  }
}

export default withNavigation(YourComponent);
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. That seemed to take care of the `undefined` error, although its not navigating to the 'Result' tab / not getting any errors.